# How can I know a radiosity linear system can be implemented using the iterative method?

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra

That is, I want to check if the linear system derived from a radiosity problem is convergent.
I also want to know is there any book/paper giving a proof on the convergence of the radiosity problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're solving  `B = (I - rho*F) B` (based on the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosity_%283D_computer_graphics%29))

Gauss-Seidel and Jacobi iteration methods are both guaranteed to converge if the matrix is diagonally dominant (Gauss-Seidel is also guaranteed to converge if the matrix is symmetric and positive definite).

The rows of the F matrix (view factors) sum to 1, so if rho (reflectivity) is < 1, which physically it should be, the matrix will be diagonally dominant.

Comment: Thanks! Another question: Is it also true if the scene is not closed?

Comment: I think in that case, the rows of F won't sum to 1 (in which case it should still converge), but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: celion, your answer is confimed in the book Advanced Global Illumination, Stochastic Radiosity chapter. And your intuitional proof on convergent is great. Thanks.